# How to export all overdue TODOs as if they are scheduled for today

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

What I'm trying to do is to export an `.ics` file daily that can be imported to Google Calendar so that I can view all unfinished TODOs on my phone. In Emacs, I have `org-agenda` show the unfinished TODOs on today's view. How can I achieve this when exporting to iCalendar?

I'm currently using `org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files` to export the TODOs from all my agenda files. I don't want to reschedule the TODOs to today, as many of them are recurring items and I don't want the next repeat time to be based on today when I do mark them as `DONE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) to sync your `org-agenda-files` with your smartphone (you could also use a cloud storage services like Dropbox, or also WebDAV). Then, if your phone is under Android, you can use [Orgzly](https://orgzly.com/) to read and edit your TODOs.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I was actually doing this previously, but I no longer needed the bidirectional syncing from Syncthing + Orgzly, so looking for something simpler and that integrates with the calendar system better.